# Recursive sequence with elusive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am unable to find a formula for the nth term of the sequence 1,11,111,1111,11111,... where each term has n digits and all digits are ones. Also, is there some sort of formula for the general case of sequences defined in terms of precedent terms? This is not a homework problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to see the result is $9 \cdot 1+1 = 10$, $9 \cdot 11+1 = 100$, $9 \cdot 111+1 = 1000$, etc, etc.

Hence $9T_n+1 =10^n$, so $T_n = \frac{10^n-1}{9}$.

Comment: Thanks, is there a general formula?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The sequence 2,22,222,... will be just twice the above formula, 3,33,333,... will be three times, etc, etc. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

$$So, T_n=\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{n \text{ digits}}=\sum_{0\le r\le n-1 }10^r=10^0\cdot\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}=\frac{10^n-1}9$$

Reference : Repunit [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) , [2](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/Repunit.html)