# Show that number is square of natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $2n+2$ - digit number: $11...122...25$ (there are $n$ of $11...1$ and $(n+1)$ of $22...2$) is square of natural number.

I tried to solve it by induction

First for $n=0$ we have $25=5^2$

We assume that number $11...122...25 = k^2$ (there are $n$ of $11...1$ and $(n+1)$ of $22...2$)

And need to show that number $111...1222...25$ (there are $(n+1)$ of $11...1$ and $(n+2)$ of $22...2)$ is also a square of natural, but here I have prolem to show it.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{10^k+5}{3}\right)^2$$

Comment: could you give a hint how to obtain this form?

Comment: Just look at the first few examples $\sqrt{1225}=35$, $\sqrt{112225}=335$, then $\sqrt{11122225}=33335$. Now try to guess a general formula, and then try to prove it.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585525/calculation-of-a-square-root-of-a-big-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = 11...122...25$ (the number you defined)

Let $A = 11...1$ (n of $1$s)

$S = A\cdot 10^{n+2} + 2\cdot A\cdot 10^2 + 25$

Substitute $A = \frac{10^n-1}{9}$ into the equation:

$$S = \frac{10^n-1}{9}\cdot 10^{n+2} + 2\cdot \frac{10^n-1}{9}\cdot 10^2 + 25$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = \frac{(10^n-1)\cdot 10^{n+2}}{9} +  \frac{2\cdot(10^n-1)\cdot 10^2 + 9\cdot25}{9}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = \frac{(10^n-1)\cdot 10^{n+2}+2\cdot(10^n-1)\cdot 10^2 + 225}{9}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = \frac{10^{2n+2}-10^{n+2}+2\cdot10^{n+2}-2\cdot 10^2 + 225}{9}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = \frac{10^{2n+2}+10^{n+2}+25}{9}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = \frac{(10^{n+1}+5)^2}{9}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow S = (\frac{10^{n+1}+5}{3})^2$$

$ 10^{n+1} + 5 \equiv 0 \pmod3 $

Hence S is square of a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Below is a sketch of an inductive proof.

If $\,\  f_k = 11\ldots1122\ldots2225\, =\, 33\ldots335^2 = n^2\ \,$ then
$\begin{eqnarray}   11\ldots 1122\ldots222500 \,&=&\,\ \ \, 100\,n^2\phantom{\large I^I}\\ 
\quad\quad\! {-}10\ldots 000500 \,&=&\, -300\, n\\
+225 \,&=&\   {+}225\\
\hline
\!\!\!f_{k+1}=\,\ 11\ldots11\color{#c00}12\ldots222\color{#c00}{22}5 \,&=&\  (10\,n\!-\!15)^2 =\, 33\ldots33\color{#c00}35^2
\end{eqnarray}$